# Can't set imageView by bitmap programmatically

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, drawable, setbackground

The imageView imgFirstAct I'd like to set a bitmap to programmatically, for some reason stays empty after running the program. Initially the imageView background and source are empty.

Here is the relevant imageViews XMLs:

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgFirstAct"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imgCopyBelow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_marginRight="89dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgFifthAct"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCopyBelow"
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgCaloriesBelow"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageView03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView11"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bar_fill" />
```

Here is the code:

```
private ImageView imgFirstAct;
private ImageView imgCopyBelow;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

     imgFirstAct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFirstAct);
     imgCopyBelow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCopyBelow);

     imgFirstAct.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

     Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgCopyBelow.getBackground().getCurrent()).getBitmap();

     int h = bitmap.getHeight();

     Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 100, h); 

     imgFirstAct.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Check you have a reference to your image view.
2. Use `mImg.setImageBitmap(img);` to set your bitmap.

   - When `mImg` is an `ImageView` and `img` is a `Bitmap`.

if (2) doen't work check maube there is something wrong with your bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, NickF. I've changed the code to imgFirstAct.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);, but the imageView is not set. I think that everything is OK with the bitmap because I've used it before.

Comment: Try to play with ScaleType

Comment: Thank you NickF for your help. I've just made Clear to the project and it worked. Anyway, when do I need to make Clear to the project?

Answer (score 0):

Call setContentView() before findViewById()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);  // Call your layout file
    imgFirstAct = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFirstAct);
}
```

Hope it helps (:

Comment: Thank you ching. I just forgot to post with super.onCreate and setContentView.

Comment: Are you sure that that bitmap contains the content you want? Have you tested with the debugger? Otherwise your code seems pretty nice to me

Comment: Thank you ching for your help. I've just made Clear to the project and it worked. Anyway, when do I need to make Clear to the project?

Comment: In your case it's recommended after you change the resources.

Comment: So the reason is the image is not really "included" in your project after just copying it to /drawable/. You need to build it once (which is why a Clean solved it. Eclipse builds the code after a clean) to have it referenced in the R.java